# Cannot properly mock Firebase storage. What is the best way?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, testing, jestjs

I am learning Jest now, and faced an error trying to test Firebase, specifically, storage API. It gives me an error INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition, pointing at firebase.auth().
I know for sure the issue is with storage, when I remove storage tests, everything runs successfully, including auth() APIs.

How do I properly mock firebase storage?

This is what I currently have:

```
  initializeApp: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    currentUser: user,
    auth: jest.fn(),
    firestore: jest.fn(),
    storage: jest.fn(),
  }),
}));

jest.mock("firebase/auth", () => ({
  getAuth: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(user)),
}));

jest.mock("firebase/storage", () => ({
  ref: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("data"),
  getDownloadUrl: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("some url"),
}));
```

Thank you!